# How do you create a menu populated with directory names and selectable by position in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Firstly I would like to say that it has been 10 years since I dabbled in programming and my memory of what I have learnt seems to be failing me. I hope I have included enough info for people to see what I am trying to do without going to extremes. There may be better ways to do what I have done and any suggestions will be appreciated.

I have 2 batch files, both in the parent directory, 1 to back up files in 2 sub directories of the parent directory to another sub directory a few levels down from the parent directory.

eg.
The batch files are in the directory "Test Folder"
The files to be backed up are in the location :-

```
Test Folder\LocalProfiles
```

and

```
Test Folder\SavedLocal
```

The folder where they are to be backed up to is called "Backup" with created directories using a name chosen by the users eg. "Blue" and then in another directory under that using the current Date and Time as the name of the directory, followed by the original directory. (The format of the date and time, currently 2016-04-06 23.03.15 has not been finalised as the space that I am using in the backup batch file between the date and time has been giving me problems in this batch file when restoring). So the location of the files for this user that have been backed up would be:-

```
Test Folder\Backup\Blue\2016-04-06 23.03.15\LocalProfiles
```

and

```
Test Folder\Backup\Blue\2016-04-06 23.03.15\SavedLocal
```

I have written a batch file that lists all of the user chosen directories
[1st Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COOAw.jpg)
then after the user chooses a directory they then choose a directory from the directories labeled with a date and time
[2nd Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDa61.jpg)
and then it copies the files below back to the original location.

The problem with this is that it takes time and can lead to typos, especially when putting in the date and time. I wanted to make it as fool proof as possible by creating a menu where the user can select a number corresponding with a user created directory.

The end result would be:-
1st menu screen

Select one of the following
1. Blue
2. Red
3. Green
etc.

and then display the directories with dates and times that are contained in the selected directory on the next menu screen.

2nd Menu

Select one of the following
1. 2016-04-05 21.03.28
2. 2016-04-05 21.05.51
3. 2016-04-06 23.00.14
etc.

The user would simply type the number corresponding to the selected directory and press enter.

In the end I would like to merge both batch files with a choice to backup or restore but I need this to work properly first.

The following is the code for restoring the files, without the use of menus. It works but it doesn't always handle spaces in directory names and I'm sure there would be a better way to handle the error checking and messages.

```
@echo off

if not defined in_subprocess (cmd /k set in_subprocess=y ^& %0 %*) & exit )

:Prompt for Profile Name
cls
echo.
echo Please select one of the following Profiles to load.
echo.


:: Create the list of Profiles from the Directory Names
for /d %%D in (.\Backup\*) do echo %%~nxD
echo. 


:: Prompt for Profile Name for multiple Profile Names
set "profile="
set /p profile=Please enter a Profile Name. 

:: OR

:: Consider adding Fixed Profile Name to top of list/menu as the default for quick saving of files.
:: set "profile=Default"


:: Check that the Profile exists
echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%" echo The Profile %profile% does not exist.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%" pause
if [%profile%] == [] echo A Profile must have a name. 
if [%profile%] == [] pause

:: If input is empty or doesn't exist return to the beginning.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%" goto Prompt for Profile Name
if [%profile%] == []  goto Prompt for Profile Name


:Saved
:: Create the list of Saved locations from the Directory Names

cls
echo.
echo Existing Saved Locations for the Profile named %profile%
echo.
for /d %%S in (".\Backup\%profile%\*") do echo %%~nxS


:: Prompt for Saved location for selected Profile Name

set "save="

echo.
set /p save=Please enter a Saved location. 


:: Check that the Saved Location exists

echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%" echo The Saved Location %profile%\"%save%" does not exist.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%" echo Select a Saved Location from the list.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%" pause


:: Check that the Saved Location is not empty

if [%save%] == [] echo Select a Saved Location from the list. 

if [%save%] == [] pause


:: If input is empty or doesn't exist return to the beginning.

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%" goto Saved
if [%save%] == []  goto Saved


:: Check for Saved files

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" echo LocalData.profile for %profile% does not exist at location "%save%\LocalProfiles\"

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" echo LocalMember.profile for %profile% does not exist at "%save%\SavedLocal\"


:: If LocalData.profile doesn't exist display message and return to Saves.

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" echo The Save at %save% is incomplete or does not exist.

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" echo Please select another Save. 

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" Pause

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\LocalProfiles\LocalData.profile" goto Saved


:: If LocalMember.profile doesn't exist display message and return to Saves.

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" echo The Save at %save% is incomplete or does not exist.

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" echo.
if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" echo Please select another Save. 

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" Pause

if not exist ".\Backup\%profile%\%save%\SavedLocal\LocalMember.profile" goto Saved


:Load Save

:: Restore the valid Save to the original location.

echo.
echo Restoring Saved Files

robocopy ".\Backup\%profile%\%Save%\LocalProfiles" ".\LocalProfiles"
robocopy ".\Backup\%profile%\%Save%\SavedLocal" ".\SavedLocal"

echo.
echo Files Restored
pause
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "directories=localprofiles savedlocal"

CALL :zap$
:: First menu
CALL :choose blue default green red "white and puce stripes" /now

SET "userchosenname=%$choice%"

:: Don't know what format you are using for date and time.
:: I use dd/mm/yyyy and hh:mm:ss.hh
SET "backupdatestamp=%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2% %time::=.%"
SET "backupdatestamp=%backupdatestamp:~0,-3%"

CALL :choose "backup as %backupdatestamp%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /ad "%sourcedir%\%userchosenname%\" 2^>nul') DO (
 IF EXIST "%sourcedir%\%userchosenname%\%%a\localprofiles\." CALL :choose "restore from %%a"
)
CALL :choose /now "With this prompt"
FOR %%a IN (%directories%) DO (
 IF "%$choice:~0,6%"=="backup" (
  ECHO(MD "%sourcedir%\%userchosenname%\%backupdatestamp%\%%a"
  ECHO(XCOPY /s/e "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%sourcedir%\%userchosenname%\%backupdatestamp%\%%a\"
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO(XCOPY /s/e "%sourcedir%\%userchosenname%\%$choice:~13%\%%a\*" "%sourcedir%\%%a\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF

:: remove variables starting $
:ZAP$
FOR  /F "delims==" %%Z In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%Z="
GOTO :EOF

:: Make a choice
:: If a parameter is '/now' actually make a choice with prompt next-parameter
:: else accumulate choices
:choose
SET "$item=%~1"
IF NOT DEFINED $item GOTO :EOF 
IF /i "%$item%"=="/now" GOTO makechoice
IF NOT DEFINED $options cls
IF NOT DEFINED $choices SET "$choices=123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
SET "$options=%$options%%$choices:~0,1%"
SET "$choices=%$choices:~1%"
SET /a $optioncount+=1
SET "$option%$optioncount%=%~1"
ECHO(%$options:~-1% %~1
SHIFT
GOTO choose

:makechoice
IF "%~2" neq "" SET "$options=%$options% /m "%~2""
choice /c %$options%
CALL SET "$choice=%%$option%errorlevel%%%"
CALL :zap$&SET "$choice=%$choice%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required XCOPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(XCOPY` to `XCOPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

The basis of this routine is the `:choose` subroutine which accumulates options into $-variables. It can be run either with 1 or more parameters, optionally quoted (in case a parameter includes a space.)

If the parameter `/now` is found, the routine asks for a choice to be made from the options presented. If the `/now` parameter is followed by another, that following parameter is used as a prompt for `choice`.

The `CALL :zap$&SET "$choice=%$choice%"` line uses the same parsing trick used to export values from a setlocal/endlocal bracket

Beyond that, all you'd need to do is fix the setting of `backupdatestamp` using the batch substringing facilities explained in the documentation

```
set /?
```

from the prompt.